# Should you check ajax return data or let javascript throw a error on empty data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So when handling, for example, the success data in jquery, should you check if the return data has the necessary data like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.new_rank !== undefined) {
        $('._user_rank').html(data.new_rank);
    }
}
```

Or let it fail when it is not present?

```
success: function (data) {
    $('._user_rank').html(data.new_rank);
}
```

in the previous example you can check if something has changed and needs to be fixt because of the error.

What approach is the best?

Comment: If you can fix it check for it

Comment: This is pretty opinion based really - it depends on how much you care about whether or not you end up displaying `undefined` in your UI, or how much you trust whatever page you've called to have populated the data correctly on a successful call etc etc.

Comment: And ensure the scope is limited sufficiently so that you are not attempting to handle anything you hadn't accounted for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better you check it, for other code that may be you have in complete or other event. If you didn't, they will not run after error. You can check it this too:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.new_rank) {
        $('._user_rank').html(data.new_rank);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery ajax requests provide you a way to handle request errors.

```
$.ajax(url, {
      success: function(data) {
          // success
      },
      error: function() {
         // error
      }
   });
```

If it's not a request error that you are trying to catch you still should handle error by yourself and not let javascript throw them all the way.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I would say is follow strict data type in $.ajax like `dataType: json`.
Use success and error handler. And if the return data is anything other than json type it will be handled through error handler.

```
$.ajax(url, {
      dataType: 'json'
      success: function(data) {
          // success
      },
      error: function() {
         // error
      }
   });
```